# How do I communicate with my app on AWS ECS Fargate if not using ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I've launched a golang based http server into AWS Fargate and I can see from the cloudwatch logs that it is up and running.  However I created the Service without an ELB.  Is an ELB required to 'ping' or communicate with my running app?  I don't see any other way of accessing the running processes.  What is the public IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ECS Cluster:

1. Click the Task ID
2. Look for the network section, specifically ENI ID
3. Click ENI ID, you should now be in the Network Interface section of EC2
4. Look for IPv4 Public IP